# An idiom for "this was only a small part of"

Tags: idiom-requests

In this sentence:

> His deteriorating health, poverty and persecution by the authorities, all this was ***but a small part of*** the trials he had to endure in those years.

I wonder if there is any idiom that could liven this sentence. Looking on the internet I found the expression ***a drop in a bucket*** ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-drop-in-the-bucket)), meaning "small part of a bigger whole", but it doesn't really fit in my sentence and it is not very elegant either. I would need something more formal and it can be poetic, too. It must integrate well in the structure of the given sentence.

Comment: This is a "list-type" question, with any number of alternative answers. The ones that actually get posted here ***are as nothing compared to*** the answers that *could* be posted (the former is ***dwarfed by*** the latter).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I doubt there are so many that could fit in this sentence as it is though.

Comment: Many relevant expressions (including your *drop in the bucket / ocean*) require either explicit inclusion of something along the lines of ***compared to*** OR highly stylised phrasing (as with Edwin's suggestion). But there are plenty like ***dwarfed, eclipsed, overshadowed*** that don't. I'm not convinced there's much point in asking for "idioms" with the required sense, given there are plenty of "transparent" usages to choose from anyway. But regardless of that, I think you're essentially asking for Off-Topic "writing advice" here.

Comment: I agree. This question leads to a lot of opinions because there are many acceptable answers, not one (or even few) correct ones.

Answer (score 1):

This was merely/just/but *the tip of the iceberg*.

> *The idiom **tip of the iceberg** basically means the small part of a much larger situation or problem that remains hidden. When only a part
> of something that can be easily observed, but not the rest of it, we
> say that the part is just the tip of the iceberg.*

[[MissouriStateEducation: Idiom](https://blogs.missouristate.edu/international/2020/05/27/idiom-tip-of-the-iceberg/#:%7E:text=The%20idiom%20%27tip%20of%20the,the%20tip%20of%20the%20iceberg.)]

- His deteriorating health, poverty and persecution by the authorities, all this was but the tip of the iceberg – there were many more trials that he had to endure in those years.

Comment: Good one! However,  I cannot say "all this was but the tip of the iceberg of the trials he had to endure"... can I?

Comment: No, icebergs tend to be more standalone;  I've given a rephrasing to get round the non-availability of 'the tip of the iceberg of ...'.