# What are alternative phrases or idioms to "only one part of the equation"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

I am writing an article and trying to explain that people search for solutions on the wrong track. Instead, they have to see the whole story to the topic.

My idea was to say something like

> "... is only one part of the equation".

Is there a better way to describe that achieving the topic/what my article is about requires another disregarded element?

Comment: You could say, _**This is/reflects only one aspect of the problem**_. It's commonly used.

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/558736/an-idiom-for-this-was-only-a-small-part-of) was downvoted, but it may be of some help.

Comment: @fev "Reflect" is not too good:  (OALD) "show or be a sign of the nature of somebody's attitude or feeling", (SOED) **5** _fig_ Reproduce or display after the fashion of a mirror; correspond in appearance or effect to (ex.: The quality of the top appointments was reflected in those lower down. Jacqueline's face reflected the intense joy  or anguish of the music). Looking at this [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22reflects%20only%20a%20part%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) it can be seen that two elements are needed.

Comment: @fev I've looked at the linked question and "tip of the iceberg" comes close but does not  fit this specific case. In my article, there are two elements that both make up the "sum/topic of my article" equally. And one element is less known - hence, the article is intended to highlight this "dark element".

Comment: "This is only part of the answer" is more common, but may not fit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use the term "... ***is one facet of*** {the subject}"

As defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facet)

> any of the definable aspects that make up a subject (as of
> contemplation) or an object (as of consideration)

Comment: That one is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: I think facet is good here because it brings in the idea of small planar surfaces created on gemstones. A “problem” is always a construction in the human mind, and when we consider a problem, it’s like looking at a cut gem from one viewpoint at a time.

Comment: @Global Charm that is a great analogy.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't really better ways, only a rather large number of ways with each its particular flavour, and in the end it is up to you to choose which appears to correspond best to your taste. For instance, "equation" is a rather technical term, and it is not necessarily in the best taste for all subjects, but that  is still in part a matter of point of view. Here are three cases that will do as alternatives.

- this covers only part of the question
- this takes into account only part of the topic
- this treats the subject only in part

Answer (score 0):

There is the expression ***the other/opposite/flip side of the coin*** which means

> a different way of looking at or thinking about a situation
>
> - The economy is improving, but the other side of the coin is that inflation is becoming a bigger problem. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20other%2Fopposite%2Fflip%20side%20of%20the%20coin))

One option could be to say

> This is only one side of the coin.

Or you could use the proverb

***THERE ARE TWO SIDES TO EVERY STORY (COIN)*** -

> "There's always a different point of view, which is entitled to be
> heard. The proverb has been traced back in English to 1742, and is
> first attested in the United States in the 1802 'Diary and
> Autobiography of John Adams' and an 1817 letter of Thomas Jefferson.
> The proverb was first expressed in ancient times, as far back as
> 485-410 B.C. Protagoras said that 'there are two sides to every
> question.' In about 428 B.B., Euripides said, 'In a case of
> dissension, never dare to judge till you've heard the other side.' The
> word ***argument, coin, everything, question*** or ***quarrel*** may replace
> ***(every) story***." From Random House Dictionary of Popular Proverbs and
> Sayings by Gregory Y. Titelman (Random House, New York, 1996). ([Phrases.org](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/28/messages/653.html))

Comment: Thank you. Do these phrases always imply that "the other side of the story/coin" is regarded as negative?

Comment: Not if you choose to say "There are two sides..." It just means that the approach in question is not the only one. The second is just as valid. [This](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/flip_side_of_the_coin/synonyms) may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

**[Only/just one piece of the puzzle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one%20piece%20of%20the%20puzzle%2C%20one%20part%20of%20the%20equation%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20piece%20of%20the%20puzzle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20part%20of%20the%20equation%3B%2Cc0)** is a slightly less technical and more common way (according to Ngram) to express the same thing as *only/just one part of the equation.*

Here are a few examples:

[Mindset Is Only One Piece of the Puzzle: Innovating Leadership, Co-Creating Our Future](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/mindset-is-only-one-piece-of-the-puzzle/id1019665822?i=1000526507479)

[With all of the publicity on the potential impact of genomic information, it can be easy to overlook a critical fact: genes are just one piece of the puzzle.](https://cpmc.coriell.org/Sections/Medical/ComplexDisease_mp.aspx?PgId=96)

[Masks are only one piece of the puzzle when it comes to curtailing the coronavirus.](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=828655164718365)

[MARKET WATCH; Rates Are Just One Piece of the Puzzle](http://MARKET%20WATCH;%20Rates%20Are%20Just%20One%20Piece%20of%20the%20Puzzle)

[Reddit made the headlines, but for the man who made millions, that was just one piece of the puzzle](https://twitter.com/ringer/status/1365835641418706946?lang=en)

[As a company dedicated to supporting your physical well-being, we recognize that this is simply one piece of the puzzle.](https://thegoodpatch.com/pages/ambition)